# Wordpress PWA with Form

Tags: plugins

Is it possible to use a form in a wordpress pwa.  I am using the SuperPWA plugin and have a form on the site, the main focus on the site to collect data which is sent to google sheets..works fine.   Will I be able capture data if the user is out of connectivity.

Ted

Comment: That would depend on the form plugin. They would need to be designed to work in a PWA. You should ask the plugin author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the service worker does not proxy (cache) POST requests so no, by design, it's not possible. However... More than one PWA do do just this. As one of the comments says, you need to contact the form plugin author for support.

Reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270702/can-service-workers-cache-post-requests

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Comment: I did look up the plugin vendor.  It has an addon that allows offline posts.  However the user would be forced to go back through each entry and resend each one.  Sounds counter productive.  I'll have to contact my people to see how often the use will be out of signal range, and if alot then maybe ill have to another approach like indexed db.

Thanks for your help.

Ted

I will mark this as answered